# jquery autoscroll plugin not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I am sure my issue is a result of my inexperience in jquery and javascript. I am trying to use an autoscroll jquery plugin. I just stares at me when I click the link that is supposed to activate the scroll. Can someone help? Here is what I have:
I have called the relevant scripts in the `head` tag.
In at the end of my body tag I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a.hello").click(function () {
    $("#text").autoscroll("toggle", { 
        start: { 
            step: 50, 
            scroll: true, 
            direction: "down", 
            pauseOnHover: true 
        }, 
        delay: 5000, 
        ffrw: { 
            speed: "fast", 
            step: 100 
        } 
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Then, I am trying to fire the script using an anchor, like this:

```
<a href="#" class="hello">start/stop</a>
```

The id of the `div` that I want to 'pause on hover' is "text".
The source and instructions of this plugin is found [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6266559/jQuery.plugins/Demo.aautoscroll.htm). Thanks.
EDIT:
The function that calls some html from other files based on form selects and puts it into the `<div id="text"></div>`.

```
function clickMe() {
    var book = document.getElementById("book").value;
    var chapter = document.getElementById("chapter").value;
    var myFile = "'files/" + book + chapter + ".html'";
    $('#text').load(myFile + '#source')
}
```

Comment: Can you show your implementation of #text?

Comment: simply, `<div id="text"></div>`. then I use the jquery `load()` function to call some html from a set of files based on an appropriate selection from a set of form selects. Here is the actual temp [site](http://www.bible.preahkumpii.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to wrap the code inside a

```
$(document).ready(function() {
..
});
```